# Add GET parameter in request adapter of Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying in the [Request Adapter of Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#adapting-and-retrying-requests) to add a GET parameter. However in the request adapter I am only able to add HTTPHeader fields.

Currently my `request adapter` looks like:

```
// MARK: - RequestAdapter

func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
    if let url = urlRequest.url, url.lastPathComponent.hasPrefix(baseURLString) {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest

        // Want to inject param here
        // e.g. urlRequest.addParam(param: "session", value: sessionToken")

        return urlRequest
    }

    return urlRequest
}
```

I have a Router configured for the Paths but since I want my AuthHandler to be responsible to all Authentication related stuff I want to inject my sessionToken. This makes sure, together with `RequestRetrier` that any HTTP 401 related error is dealt with.

What is the best way to change the urlRequest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try

```
let params: Parameters = ["session": sessionToken]
return URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: params)
```

(or)

```
return URLEncoding.queryString.encode(urlRequest, with: params)
```

Thanks
Sriram

Comment: If I already set some parameters when creating the Alamofire request, does this just add to them or replace them?

Comment: @Augie It creates a URL request by encoding parameters and applying them onto an existing request.